# Communicate between a client computer and a vps server JAVA

Tags: java, sockets, vps, irc

i know there is alot of post that ask how to comunicate between client and server ,but in the majority those are generally people using the localhost, I have for project to use a vps and several client computer, unfortunately all the solutions given in the other post does not work, indeed the client does not seem to be able to connect to my vps

there is my client code

```
    public IRCClient() throws IOException {
        socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[]{(byte) 185, (byte) 242, (byte) 180,97}), 2406);
        messages = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Object>();
        server = new ConnectionToServer(socket);

        Thread messageHandling = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        Object message = messages.take();
                        parse(message);
                        System.out.println("Message Received: " + message);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        messageHandling.setDaemon(true);
        messageHandling.start();
    }

    private void parse(Object message) {
        String msg = String.valueOf(message);
        if (msg.contains("-")) {
            if (msg.contains("key")) {
                key = msg.split("-")[1];
            } else if (msg.contains("name")) {
                name = msg.split("-")[1];
            } else if (msg.contains("world")) {
                world = msg.split("-")[1];
            } else if (msg.contains("server")) {
                serverName = msg.split("-")[1];
            } else if (msg.contains("x")) {
                x = Integer.parseInt(msg.split("-")[1]);
            } else if (msg.contains("y")) {
                y = Integer.parseInt(msg.split("-")[1]);
            } else if (msg.contains("z")) {
                z = Integer.parseInt(msg.split("-")[1]);
            } else if (msg.contains("isEntity")) {
                entity = msg.split("-")[1].equalsIgnoreCase("true");
            } else if (msg.contains("ticks")) {
                lTicks = Integer.parseInt(msg.split("-")[1]);
            } else if (msg.contains("end")) {
                if (key.equalsIgnoreCase(MultiPingMod.getKey()) && !name.equalsIgnoreCase(Minecraft.getMinecraft().thePlayer.getName())) {
                    MultiPing m = new MultiPing(name, world, serverName, x, y, z, entity);
                    MultiPingMod.setTime(lTicks);
                    m.render = true;
                    if (MultiPingMod.render.getToRender().containsKey(name)) {
                        MultiPingMod.render.getToRender().get(name).render = false;
                        MultiPingMod.render.getToRender().remove(name);
                    }
                    MultiPingMod.render.addToRender(m);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void send(Object obj) {
        server.write(obj);
    }

    private class ConnectionToServer {
        ObjectInputStream in;
        ObjectOutputStream out;
        Socket socket;

        ConnectionToServer(Socket socket) throws IOException {
            this.socket = socket;
            in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            Thread read = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    while (true) {
                        try {
                            Object obj = in.readObject();
                            messages.put(obj);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            read.setDaemon(true);
            read.start();
        }

        private void write(Object obj) {
            try {
                out.writeObject(obj);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    }
}
```

i got this code from somewhere in this forum because after lot of attempt nothing was working
same for the server code here is :

```
  public ServerListener() {
       debug("Creating the server");
       clientList = new ArrayList<ConnectionToClient>();
       messages = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Object>();
       debug("Client list is created");
       try {
           serverSocket = new ServerSocket(2406);
           debug("opening the port 2406");
       } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
           debug(e.getMessage());
       }
    debug("creating the accept thread");
       Thread accept = new Thread() {
           public void run() {
    debug("thread created");
               while (true) {
                   try {
                       Socket s = serverSocket.accept();
if(s!=null) {
                       debug("new client joined");
                       clientList.add(new ConnectionToClient(s));
                       debug("new client was accepted ["+ s.getInetAddress() + "/" + s.getPort()+"]");
                
}
 } catch (IOException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                      debug(e.getMessage());
                   }
               }
           }
       };
       accept.setDaemon(true);
       accept.start();

       Thread messageHandling = new Thread() {
           public void run() {
               while (true) {
                   try {
                       Object message = messages.take();
                       debug("we parse the ping");
                       parse(message);
                       System.out.println("Message Received: " + message);
                   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                   }
               }
           }
       };

       messageHandling.setDaemon(true);
       messageHandling.start();
   }

   private void parse(Object message) {
       String msg = String.valueOf(message);
       if(msg.contains("-")) {
           if(msg.contains("key")) {
               debug("key detected");
               key = msg.split("-")[1];
           } else if(msg.contains("name")) {
               debug("name detected");
               name = msg.split("-")[1];
           } else if(msg.contains("world")) {
               debug("worldname detected");
               world = msg.split("-")[1];
           } else if(msg.contains("server")) {
               debug("servername detected");
               server = msg.split("-")[1];
           } else if(msg.contains("x")) {
               debug("x detected");
               x = Integer.parseInt(msg.split("-")[1]);
           } else if(msg.contains("y")) {
           debug("y detected");
               y = Integer.parseInt(msg.split("-")[1]);
           } else if(msg.contains("z")) {
                debug("z detected");
               z = Integer.parseInt(msg.split("-")[1]);
           } else if(msg.contains("isEntity")) {
                   debug("entity detected");
               entity = msg.split("-")[1].equalsIgnoreCase("true");
           } else if(msg.contains("ticks")) {
               debug("ticks detected");
               lTicks = Integer.parseInt(msg.split("-")[1]);
           } else if(msg.contains("end")) {
               debug("we got everything detected");
               toSend = new IrcMPING(key, name, world, server, x, y, z, entity, lTicks);
               for(String str : toSend.getArgs()) {
                   
                   sendToAll(str);
               }
               toSend=null;
           }
       }
   }

   public void sendToOne(int index, Object message) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
       clientList.get(index).write(message);
   }

   public void sendToAll(Object message) {
       for (ConnectionToClient client : clientList) {
           debug("sending the ping to " + client.socket.getInetAddress());
           client.write(message);
       }
   }

   public void debug(String str) {
           System.out.println("SOROS DEBUG [MULTIPING] : " + str) ;
     
       }

   private class ConnectionToClient {
       ObjectInputStream in;
       ObjectOutputStream out;
       Socket socket;

       ConnectionToClient(Socket socket) throws IOException {
           this.socket = socket;
           in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
           out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

           Thread read = new Thread() {
               public void run() {
                   while (true) {
                       try {
                           Object obj = in.readObject();
                           messages.put(obj);
                       } catch (IOException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                       } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                       }
                   }
               }
           };

           read.setDaemon(true); // terminate when main ends
           read.start();
       }

       public void write(Object obj) {
           try {
     
               out.writeObject(obj);
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
       
    
   }

}
```

i run the jar from the vps (who is based on debian) using the java jar command , but nothing to do i only get this on the terminal

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/832578338567487497/833752196017029170/unknown.png //link to the image

How can i do to make this work ? there is any other way than socket to make two jar communicate from distant computer/server ? thank you for reading me and thank you if you try to help me

Comment: I don't see anywhere what ip you are binding to. Perhaps you are binding to 127.0.0.1? Maybe check with ```netstat -an``` what ip port 2406 is listening on.

Comment: @wowbagger actually im binding to 185.242.180.97 the domain is samuele.site, but even when i use the domain name the client doesnt connect to the server by the way , port are not free ? i mean i cant just choose a random port number ? i trought it was working like that , with netstat -an can i get the port who are free and who i can use ?

Comment: you can choose any port you like, as long as it's not yet in use. You can check what ports are in use with ```netstat -an```. Don't try to use an ip:port combination that's already in use, your program won't be able to bind and won't start.

Comment: you can also use netcat to check if you can just TCP connect to the ip:port combination with: ```nc -v 185.242.180.97 2406``` .

Comment: A quick way to check if you're not having firewall issues is to run netcat in listening mode on your VPS: ```nc -l 185.242.180.97 2406``` and from another machine see if you can connect to it with ```nc -v 185.242.180.97 2406```. If it's connected you'll see everything you type being pushed down the connection to the other terminal.

Comment: thank you very much @wowbagger so i tried everything and https://pastebin.com/AxSqciQ6 this is what i get with "netstat -an" with nc -v 185.242.180.97 2406
nc: connect to 185.242.180.97 port 2406 (tcp) failed: Connection refused but nc -l 185.242.180.97 2406 just blocked my vps , so it look like the problem come from the ip or the port , what can i do to fix that ? use another port ?

Comment: nc -l 185.242.180.97 2406 doesnt block the vps , my bad the vps just wait for a connection

Comment: Hi Soros, that ```netstat -an``` doesn't show any ports listening? Are you sure it's complete?
This https://pastebin.com/fQWYfSgv is an example from a server. 
You can see for example something listening on 172.23.1.17 port 443 (172.23.1.17:443). You can dig deeper with ```lsof -i -P -n``` which would show you the actual program listening on that port: https://pastebin.com/CY7qUQGL